# read_user_chunkIDOT:1221 swift 4

Tags: ios, base64, swift4

I am developing an iOS application with Swift 4(Xcode 9.2).

I create events with my app and I add a photo from my iPhone Library as the event image.I encode it with base64 then I store it into the database as String.

But when I want to decode and display it, I get a black image and this error :

```
read_user_chunkIDOT:1221: invalid PNG file: no valid iEnd chunk
```

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k97WS.png) may explain more the issue.

Here is my code when encoding :

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        let imageData:Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()    
}}
```

The code when decoding:

```
 let imagedecoded = Data(base64Encoded: event.image, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    imageEvent.image = UIImage(data: imagedecoded)!
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you add the image which causes this?

Comment: Ditto what @Ryan said.  Need the failing image. The code you have above works fine with PNG's I've looked at.  Also are you sure that 'event.image' is exactly the 'base64String' that got encoded?   No extra manipulation/conversion?

Comment: I import the image from my iPhone.

Comment: I encode the image and I store it in the database and when I get it from the database in another controller , this problem occured :(